# How do I set custom response headers from an EC2 ALB?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am finding it hard to get info on how to set custom response headers from an Amazon ALB. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

ALB has no mechanism for injecting custom headers in either direction.  Your back-end targets will need to include whatever response headers you need to return with each response.

If you are using CloudFront in front of ALB, you can also inject custom response header using Lambda@Edge an origin-response or viewer-response trigger.